# Using the same class multiple times in a row in CSS/LESS

Tags: css, less

This might be a dumb question, but I couldn't find an answer by searching here or with Google. I've been doing web design a few years now, but in some code at work I noticed this:

```
.header-silver,
.header-silver,
.header-silver,
.header-silver {
    #gradient >.vertical(#FEFEFE, #E1E1E1);
}
```

I didn't write this, but as far as I know, using the same class like that is very redundant. Is there something I've missed in my quest in learning CSS/LESS, and there a chance that the person that wrote this used it for a reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class wrapper `.header-silver` is redundant.

My previous notion on the `#gradient` is wrong as ScottS mentioned below. I missed the part where it is a mixin call and not a style.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for clearing that up. And you're probably right about the `#gradient`, but I'll check it out just in case.

Comment: I agree that it is redundant with respect to the multiple `.header-silver` calls. I disagree that it is "redundant completely as an ID is used" because that is not what the code `#gradient >.vertical(#FEFEFE, #E1E1E1);` is doing. In LESS syntax, that is a call to a [namespaced mixin](http://lesscss.org/#-namespaces) in the `#gradient` namespace. So the CSS code for `.header-silver` is being generated through the mixin called inside the `#gradient` namespace. The `#gradient` is _not_ part of the selector string in relation to `.header-silver`, and thus it is not redundant on that account.

Comment: @ScottS you're totally right! My apologies, I wasn't paying enough attention.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, just the one `.header-silver` will work fine.